# How does the beach actually exist?

Tags: plot-explanation, y-tu-mama-tambien

In *Y Tu Mamá También*, Julio and Tenoch get Luisa to come with them to Boca del Cielo ("Heaven's Mouth"), a place that does not really exist. It is clear that Julio and Tenoch have made it up, and Julio even reminds Tenoch that it does not exist. Yet, they actually find a beach, and another that the locals call "Heaven's Mouth".

Is the screenwriter really saying that they made an extremely lucky guess in thinking of the name "Heaven's Mouth"?